# Spark DataFrames Scala - jump to next group during a loop

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, grouping

I have a dataframe as below and it records the quarter and date during which same incident occurs to which IDs.

[image]

I would like to mark an ID and date if the incident happen at two consecutive quarters. And this is how I did it.

```
val arrArray = dtf.collect.map(x => (x(0).toString, x(1).toString, x(2).toString.toInt))

if (arrArray.length > 0) {

  var bufBAQDate = ArrayBuffer[Any]()

  for (a <- 1 to arrArray.length - 1) {
    val (strBAQ1, strDate1, douTime1) = arrArray(a - 1)
    val (strBAQ2, strDate2, douTime2) = arrArray(a)

    if (douTime2 - douTime1 == 15 && strBAQ1 == strBAQ2 && strDate1 == strDate2) {
      bufBAQDate = (strBAQ2, strDate2) +: bufBAQDate
      //println(strBAQ2+" "+strDate2+" "+douTime2)
    }
  }

  val vecBAQDate = bufBAQDate.distinct.toVector.reverse
```

Is there a better way of doing it? As the same insident can happen many times to one ID during a single day, it is better to jump to the next ID and/or date once an ID and a date is marked. I dont want to create nested loops to filter dataframe.

Comment: What is this `dtf` ? Is this spark dataframe ?

Comment: yes the spark dataframe

Comment: Can you share schema of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you current solution misses 20210103 as 1400 - 1345 = 55

I think this does the trick

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ID")
  .orderBy("datetime_seconds")

val consecutiveIncidents = dtf.withColumn("raw_datetime", concat($"Date", $"Time"))
  .withColumn("datetime", to_timestamp($"raw_datetime", "yyyyMMddHHmm"))
  .withColumn("datetime_seconds", $"datetime".cast(LongType))
  .withColumn("time_delta", ($"datetime_seconds" - lag($"datetime_seconds", 1).over(windowSpec)) / 60)
  .filter($"time_delta" === lit(15))
  .select("ID", "Date")
  .distinct()
  .collect()
  .map { case Row(id, date) => (id, date) }
  .toList
```

Basically - convert the datetimes to timestamps, then look for records with the same ID and consecutive times, with their times separated by 15 minutes.

This is done by using `lag` over a window grouped by ID and ordered by the time.

In order to calculate the time difference The timestamp is converted to unix epoch seconds.

If you don't want to count day-crossing incidients, you can add the `date` to the groupyBy clause of the window

Comment: Thanks for the input. Am i correct to say that this solution isnt much different mine as it still check with every lag=-1 and later distinct? As it does not jump to the next ID+Date once it finds an ID+Date has one incident

Comment: @davidzxc574 Your solution has several problems:

1. It doesn't utilise spark at all, all of the program is performed after doing `collect`.
if your program runs on a small enough dataset that you don't need to use spark functions, I suggest you don't use spark at all as it is a complicated framework with a high development/testing/maintenance overhead.
2. Your code has errors, noteably addressing hours at integers, and missing day-crossing incidents.
3. Your code uses `var`, which is highly frowned upon in Scala, a functional language.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. Please also let me know a solution to jump out of  the loop for each day